# How to get a right rotation(x,y) by move vector(x,y)

Tags: math, 3d, cocos2d-x, box2d

I am developing a pool game , use box2d.

I have know the move vector(vtX,vtY) of ball, how to compute the rotation(x,y) when ball is moving.

The ball is 3D sphere, i need the rotations to rotate the ball when it is moving.

ps: in my case, i cant use the 3d physics engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express the resulting rotation as a combination of a rotation axis and an angle. I highly advise against using Euler angles as this will result in very complicated expressions if done correctly.

If your ball moves by distance `(dx, dy)`, the rotation axis is `normalize(cross(up, (dy, dy)))`, where `up` is the up-direction. Assuming that this is the z-axis, you get

```
axis = normalize(-dy, dx, 0)
```

And the angle is

```
angle = length(dx, dy) / r,
```

where `r` is the ball's radius and `length(dx, dy) = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)`. The angle will be in radians.